# Can I use previous RNG data to forward predict the PROBABILITY of the next roll being a certain value?

Tags: random, statistics, probability

Assuming you have a random number generator that output a previous dataset that contains 1,000 random numbers in the range 00.00 to 99.99 (e.g. 07.81, 84.30). Each 'roll' is discrete and independent of all prior rolls.

From this data set, is it possible to calculate the probability that the next '10' rolls will contain two cases of 25.00-50.00, three cases, of 50.00-75.00, etc.?

Comment: That is by no means a programming, but a stochastics question. But: as you've noted yourself, your random number generator needs to follow some model for this to make sense. If you don't know that model, well, then make an assumption and live with it if the assumption is wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is by no means a programming question, but a self-answering question on the bare nature of random numbers.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, If he's talking about a true RNG, then you're right. If he's referring to a PRNG, then it is computer related.

Comment: @Stargazer712 computer-related != programming related. Also, even so, "a PRNG" doesn't give me any info on what the random numbers will behave like.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, no argument there.

Answer (score 2):

For a true RNG, the answer is no--that's what distinguishes it as a RNG. Attempting to predict independent random events based on prior outcomes is called the [Gambler's Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy).

However computers almost always use PRNG (pseudo-random number generators), which use a deterministic algorithm (along with a seed) to generate the next number in a sequence in such a way that it appears to be random.

It does this using an algorithm that follows a "ring" of numbers (think of it like an enormously long trail of numbers that repeats itself--it's deterministic, but scattered in a way that appears random). The seed is used to determine where you start on this ring. Every time you call next() to get a new random number, you are really just returning the next number in the sequence (often this number is modulo some value, such as 1000, such that the number is between some requested range).

In that sense, you have the answer to your question. If you know the seed, then there's nothing random about it--you can predict with 100% accuracy what comes next. If you don't know the seed, then you need to focus on determining what seeds could have generated the sequence of numbers you have seen thus far (which is a much harder problem).

Comment: This is good comment. Maybe you could also add the split between PRNGs and CryptoPRNGS (+ maybe external entropy sources and possible mixtures). I'm not sure about the origin of this question, but if he would like to predict some stuff like online-casinos, CPRNGS are, together with external entropy-sources, a very important concept. Additionally: the problem of learning the internal state of the mersenne-twister (as an example of non-crypto PRNG) is not as hard as one might think (very few bits needed). But i'm not able to find references at the moment.